# :CtrlPBuffer should show buffer number as :ls does

Tags: vim, vim-plugin, ctrlp

Is it be possible to configure `:CtrlPBuffer` in a way that it also shows the buffer number? Same way as `:ls` does.

Maybe even the exact layout and details, that is also line number and status indicators fields.

Comment: If you want `:ls`, why don't you use `:ls`?

Comment: I use several features of `:CtrlPBuffer` like regex and fuzzy search through buffers, (split) opening selected buffers, instantly switching to fuzzy file search and so on. It's just more comfortable then using `:ls`, `:split`, etc sequentially

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a plugin for CtrlP which does exactly what you want: [ctrlp-hibuff](https://github.com/noscript/ctrlp-hibuff)

Comment: Seems like this has been integrated into CtrlP by now.